# Validar un TextFormField desde fuera del container

Tags: flutter

Tengo dentro del container mi textFormField y quiero mostrar validaciones segun la interaccion del usuario fuera del container
pues no puedo guardarlo en una variable por que esta solo toma el primewr valor y no se actualiza

```
Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Text(
              First Name *',
              style: TextStyle(color:Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                fontSize: 15,
                ),
             ),
             const Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
           ],
         ),
         Container(padding:const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
         margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 20.0),
         decoration: BoxDecoration(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
         border: Border.all(color: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 96, 128, 1))),
         child: TextFormField(
           validator: ( value ){
             if(value!.isEmpty){
               return "Enter First Name";
             }
             if(value.length < 2 || value.length > 25){
               return "very long last name !";
             }
             else{
               return null;
             }
           },
           onChanged: (text) {
             setState(() => firstName = text);
           },
           style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
           decoration: const InputDecoration(
           border: InputBorder.none,
           hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
          ),
        maxLines: null,
      ),
    )
  ],
```

como podria mostrar los mensajes del validator en fuera del container para no dañar su diseño
[image: Quiero que el texto del validator este fuera del container y se actualice de la misma forma]),[image: para que no se redimencione el container]

Answer (score 1):

Cuando usas el `validator` del `TextFormField` por defecto te agrega el mensaje de error dentro de ese widget, si quieres manejarlo separado, tendrías que cambiar un poco el código.

Ejemplo:

```dart
  String firstName = '';
  String? errorFirstName;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('LOGIN'),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'First Name *',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    fontSize: 15,
                  ),
                ),
                const Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 20.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  border:
                      Border.all(color: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 96, 128, 1))),
              child: Center(
                child: TextFormField(
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty) {
                      errorFirstName = "Enter First Name";
                    }
                    if (value.length < 2 || value.length > 25) {
                      errorFirstName = "very long last name !";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onChanged: (text) {
                    setState(() => firstName = text);
                  },
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
                  ),
                  maxLines: null,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            if (errorFirstName != null)
              Text(
                errorFirstName!,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            MaterialButton(
              child: const Text('VALIDATE'),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _formKey.currentState!.validate();
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Al `validator` se le retorna `null` para que no agregue ningún mensaje y ese texto de error lo asignas a una variable de error que crees, en este caso usé `errorFirstName`.